# Por que devemos escalar/padronizar valores das variáveis e como reverter essa transformação?

Tags: r, ciência-de-dados

Ao trabalhar com algoritmos de previsão que usam multivariáveis me deparei com a função `scale` do R, que cujo objetivo é escalar/padronizar os valores das variáveis.

Não tenho dificuldades na utilização da função `scale`, mas minha dúvida é especificamente conceitual.

Por que devo escalar os valores das minhas variáveis? Qual é o objetivo? Isso faz diferença por exemplo, na acurácia do modelo de previsão do meu algoritmo? E como posso reverter a transformação?

Comment: Veja [este post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/when-conducting-multiple-regression-when-should-you-center-your-predictor-varia) do [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Mas esqueça uma das razões dadas, a da estabilidade numérica, hoje em dia isso já não é bem verdade, os computadores estão muito melhores. Isso foi dito no [R-Help](https://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg249829.html) há algum tempo atrás.

Comment: Obrigado pelas referências @Rui Barradas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Devo escalonar minhas entradas? A reposta é: depende.

A verdade é que escalonar seus dados não irá piorar o resultado, então, na dúvida, escalone.

#### Casos em que se deve escalonar

1. Se o modelo se baseia na distância entre os pontos, como algoritmos de clusterização (k-meas) ou redução de dimensionalidade (PCA), então é necessário escalonar/normalizar suas entradas. Veja o exemplo:

Partindo dos dados:

```
    Ano  Preco
0  2000   2000
1  2010   3000
2  1970   2500
```

A matriz de distância euclidiana é:

```
       0       1       2   
0 [[   0.   1000.05  500.9 ]
1  [1000.05    0.    501.6 ]
2  [ 500.9   501.6     0.  ]]
```

Observamos que a distância absoluta do `preco` dita qual será a distância, pois seu valor absoluto é muito maior que o `ano`. Porém, quando normalizamos entre [0, 1], o resultado muda drasticamente:

```
   Ano_norm  Preco_norm
0      0.75         0.0
1      1.00         1.0
2      0.00         0.5
```

A nova matriz de distância euclidiana é:

```
      0    1    2 
0 [[0.   1.03 0.9 ]
1  [1.03 0.   1.12]
2  [0.9  1.12 0.  ]]
```

Outro exemplo, referente ao PCA, é [este aqui](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_scaling_importance.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-preprocessing-plot-scaling-importance-py).

2. Para algoritmos como Redes Neurais ([veja esta referência](https://towardsdatascience.com/why-data-should-be-normalized-before-training-a-neural-network-c626b7f66c7d)), que utilizam o gradiente descendente e funções de ativação, escalonar as entradas permite:

   - Que features só positivas possuam uma parte negativa e outra positiva, o que facilita o treinamento.
   - Evita que alguma conta retorne valores como `Not a Number` durante o treinamento.
   - Se as entradas estiverem em escalas diferentes, os pesos conectados aos inputs serão atualizados em ritmos diferentes (alguns mais rápidos que outros). Isto prejudica o aprendizado.

E ainda normalizar as saídas é importante por conta da função de ativação da última camada.

Neste caso, para voltar a escala original da saída, basta guardar os valores utilizados para normalizar e fazer a conta inversa. Ex:

Para normalizar:

```
X_norm = (X - X_min)/(X_max - X_min)
```

Para voltar a escala original:

```
X = X_norm * (X_max - X_min) + X_min
```

#### Casos em que não é necessário escalonar

1. Algoritmos de corte, como Árvore de decisão e Random Forest.

#### Outros casos

Para alguns algoritmos como regressão linear, escalonar não é obrigatório e não melhora a acurácia. Escalonar ou não as entradas mudará apenas os coeficientes encontrados. Porém, como as entradas possuem magnitudes diferentes (como no exemplo acima de `ano` e `preço`), os coeficientes encontrados só poderão ser comparados se as entradas forem escalonadas. Ou seja, se quiser interpretabilidade, escalone as entradas.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @AlexCiuffa, me esclareceu muitas dúvidas. Se me permite gostaria de perguntar mais uma coisa e se puder responder ficaria muito grato. Você mencionou que em Regressão Linear escalonar não melhora na acurácia, mas e se eu usar o ARIMA seria o mesmo caso?

Comment: Como o ARIMA só utiliza a própria variável temporal como entrada, a escala das entradas é a mesma, por isso não há necessidade de escaloná-las. Inclusive, a escala da saída é a mesma das entradas.

Comment: Entendi. Mesmo que eu inclua multivariáveis no modelo do ARIMA também não tem necessidade? Eu fiz alguns testes e não vi diferença, não sei quanto a interpretabilidade se muda algo.

Comment: O ARIMA é uma regressão linear que tem como entrada um (ou mais) histórico(s). Por isso escalonar as entradas não irá melhorar o resultado.

Comment: Entendi. Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento.